# Attempts to get path of a resource result in NullPointerExceptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Changing path to hardcoded string - works, however this is not an option.
Test fails because it cannot find the resource, even though it's there.

**Cities.java**

```
    /*
This Singleton Class loads cities.json into an ArrayList and by using a boolean method isCity can tell if passed
String is city or not.
 */
public class Cities
{
    private static Cities single_instance = null;
    ArrayList<City> cityArrayList;

    private Cities() throws IOException
    {
        String path = new ClassPathResource("cities.json").getFile().getAbsolutePath();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type cityListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<City>>()
        {
        }.getType();
        cityArrayList = gson.fromJson(new FileReader(path), cityListType);
    }

    public static Cities getInstance() throws IOException
    {
        if (single_instance == null)
            single_instance = new Cities();
        return single_instance;
    }

    public boolean isCity(String cityToLookFor)
    {
        for (City city : cityArrayList)
        {
            if (city.getName().strip().equalsIgnoreCase(cityToLookFor))
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**CitiesTest.java**

```
class CitiesTest
{
    Cities cities = Cities.getInstance();

    CitiesTest() throws IOException {}


    @Test
    void isCityTest2()
    {
        assertFalse(cities.isCity("USA"), "City not found in localDbase");
    }

    @Test
    void isCityTest3()
    {
        assertEquals(true, cities.isCity("Paris"), "City not found in localDbase");
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

https://pastebin.com/fMQNknM1

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [cities.json] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

```
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:195)
at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:150)
at gr.serresparc.palantir.repository.Cities.<init>(Cities.java:24)
at gr.serresparc.palantir.repository.Cities.getInstance(Cities.java:35)
at gr.serresparc.palantir.repository.CitiesTest.<init>(CitiesTest.java:12)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a slash / in front of the resource path? If your resource is in the root of your classpath then it should start with a slash.

Comment: I have, didn't change anything.

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot, is the json file under src/main/resources ? Also, if json is inside a directory, include that in the path.

Comment: json file is inside src/main/resources.

Comment: Is the file in the same project as the test? And by the way, why do you insist on reading the content as file when in fact it is a classpath resource?

Comment: Yes, it is. Because I'm out of ideas. 
Also, when running All Tests in Intellij
https://imgur.com/a/LDGeGVZ
Is it supposed to say <default package> ?

Comment: Could you please tell us what the exists() method on the ClasspathResource says?

Comment: If exists() say false could you please tell us about your project structure and where the mentioned files (the two Java classes and the json file) are in the project? If it says true go for the InputStream as suggested by @Saraubh.

Comment: Could you please also remove the `<targetPath>..</targetPath>` from your pom.xml? As a matter of fact, I would remove the whole `resource` section. This probably **fixes** the issue.

Comment: Your IDE says defaultPackage because the classes have no `package`.

Comment: The thinking mistake is the *there* part of the 'even though it's there'. The correct *there* is `target/classes` not  `src/main/resources`.

Comment: You were right, it works now. However jar file can't locate resource.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203433/discussion-between-michal-and-crow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `<targetPath>..</targetPath>` from the `resources` section of the `pom.xml`. You might as well remove the whole `resources` section.

The executed test code is not looking for the file in within `src/main/resources` but within `target/classes`. The classpath resource `cities.json` needs to appear there.

Please be also aware that if the application is shipped as a spring boot jar file then it is not possible to read a classpath resource as file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the code as below,

```
String path = new ClassPathResource("classpath:cities.json").getFile().getAbsolutePath();
```

Please, note I have added `classpath:` in front of `cities.json`.

**EDIT**

You can also get the `InputStreamReader` like below, First, inject `ResourceLoader`.

```
@Autowired
ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
```

Then load json file just like below:

```
cityArrayList = gson.fromJson(new JsonReader(resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:cities.json").getInputStream()), cityListType);
```

Comment: Static analysis failed, suggested I use valueOf(), I did and the result is the same. I swear there's a demon in my computer. None of this makes sense.